# Extruding happens in 2D instead of 3D

Tags: modeling, objects, extrude

I'm a noob to this so its a noob question. When I try to extrude a model it does it 2d instead of 3d. Can someone help me? I've tried looking at videos but none show what I want.

Comment: hello, you don't give enough details about your problem, what's happening, etc... please provide details, pictures...

Comment: If the object has any volume (i.e it's not a plane but e.g. a cube) then extruding will always be in 3D. It might seem from the current view point it's flat though. Note to use either Quad view or rotate view constantly to check how your mesh looks

Comment: ...also be aware of your selection mode you're in, when editing (vertex, edge, or face). Extrusion works in all three, producing edges from disconnected vertices, and faces from edges or vertices which are connected along edges.

Comment: if your model has some crazy scale on one of the axes it will look flat.

Answer (score 3):

When extruding you can press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> in order to force axis along which it should extrude.

You can also press <kbd>E</kbd> to start extruding, <kbd>ESC</kbd> to reset extrusion position (but it still keeps extruded geometry selected), then you can grab any of the direction axes (3 coloured arrows) that will let you move the extrusion in any direction you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want en extrusion of a selection of faces in *more* than one direction, you can either extrude a connected region along its vertex normals, or individual faces along their own face normals ..  check out the options when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.